# IE11 different behavior between cached and uncached JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer-11

I have an Angular 6 application. The generated HTML from the build references these JS files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.7e3855236bac2de104f2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.8e212f269495fb61f755.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.1b1c75d8cf76e4b141af.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.814126c374dc80ced8d1.js"></script>
```

When the application is loaded the first time I can see that these files are loaded from the server. The problem is that after this initial load nothing happens. Angular doesn't lazy load the required module and no error is logged to the console.

When I refresh the page I can see that these files are loaded from the browser cache. Angular now lazy loads the required modules and everything works as expected.

I can reproduce this behavior in IE11 all the time so it seems to me that the problem is related to loading the JS files from the server vs. loading the JS files from the browser cache.

I have tweaked the build settings in angular.json. If I set

```
"optimization": false,
"buildOptimizer": false
```

then the problem goes away most of the time. But in 10% of the pages loads from the server it still appears. After reverting it back to

```
"optimization": true,
"buildOptimizer": true
```

the problem is reproducible all the time.

Any idea why there is a difference between JS files loaded from the server vs. loaded from the browser cache? Why do the build parameters affect the behavior?

Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Edit:
I found another difference in the IE devtools.

From the server:
[image: From server]
From the cache:
[image: From cache]

As you can see there is no initiator in the cached version.

Another difference I found in the response headers.

The cached version return Content-Length, Content-Type and ETag. The uncached version returns Content-Length, Content-Type, ETag, Accept-Ranges, Date, Last-Modified and Server.

Accept-Ranges has the value of "bytes".

Comment: Is this https or http? What are the response headers related to store and cache? I have seen issues in IE1 with cache when served over https and when certain headers are present.

Comment: @sabithpocker see my edits at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @spreiter301 when you say "after this initial load nothing happens" what do you mean?  we've had user reports of our site failing to load but have always put it down to them having a very slow internet connection